# Cannot access Nifi Web UI after set nifi.web.http.host

Tags: apache-nifi, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari, hortonworks-dataflow

I have a problem about Nifi Web UI. When I set nifi.web.http.host=luan-ht01, I could not access Nifi Web UI on browsers by public IP, example: http://localhost:8080/nifi/, http://107.113.193.160:8080/nifi. I only could access Nifi Web by host name. 
Do you have any solutions?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your experience is the expected behavior -- when you set the hostname explicitly, that is the address on which NiFi will respond. You can leave that property value blank to have NiFi respond on all available hosts, (i.e. `localhost`, `127.0.0.1`, etc.). During startup, the `$NIFI_HOME/logs/nifi-app.log` file will show a listing like below, enumerating all listening hosts.

```
2378   │ 2019-06-18 14:25:20,738 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer NiFi has started. The UI is available at the following URLs:
2379   │ 2019-06-18 14:25:20,738 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer https://node1.nifi:9441/nifi
2381   │ 2019-06-18 14:25:20,740 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.BootstrapListener Successfully initiated communication with Bootstrap
2382   │ 2019-06-18 14:25:20,740 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Controller initialization took 93674324706 nanoseconds (93 seconds).
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I solved my problem. I set nifi.web.http.host="ip address".

Answer (score 0):

One quick work-around for you could be to create an "alias" for your localhost IP address to be named as your domain (just for testing purposes on your local environment, of course):

On GNU/Linux based systems, just edit (with `sudo` privileges) your `/etc/hosts` file, and add another line like that one for localhost:

*/etc/hosts*

```
127.0.0.1        localhost
127.0.0.1        luan-ht01
```

In Windows systems, the *hosts* file would (usually) be found at:

```
c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts
```

By doing so, you'll now be able to direct your browser to `http://luan-ht01:8080/nifi` and hopefully will be getting your web UI back.

Enjoy ;)

Comment: Thank you very much. I changed my host file.